# Populate GridView with resultset of stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've been struggling with displaying the resultset of a stored procedure in a grid view on the click of a button.

My issue is that am working on the existing code of a portal based on 3-tier architecture which doesn't allow me to use stuff like `SqlDataAdapter` and such. Because such functionality have already been incorporated by some methods which are available in the form of dlls.

I've tried returning a `DataTable` or a `DataSet` as the data source of the gridview but in vain.

Please help me by suggesting if there is any alternative object that can be assigned to the datasource of the gridview.. I am new to all this.. Any help is most appreciated !!

Here is my code:

DataAccess Layer:

```
public IDataReader BindGridView(string rgn)
{
    string spdName = "spd_get_default_region";
    DbCommand cmd = DB.GetStoredProcCommand(spdName);
    DB.AddInParameter(cmd, "Rgn", DbType.String, rgn);
    IDataReader idr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    return  idr;
}
```

Here, `GetStoredProcCommand` is a built-in method. `gvAll` is the ID of the gridview.

Grid.aspx.cs:

```
protected void Go_Rgn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    DAL da=new DAL();
    plhTable.Visible = true;
    plhChoose.Visible = false;
    plhForm.Visible = false;
    string Rgn = afRgn.Text;
    gvAll.DataSource = da.BindGridView(Rgn);
    gvAll.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple alternative is to create a dataTable object.

```
DataTable defaultRegion = new DataTable();
defaultRegion.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
gvAll.DataSource = table;
gvAll.DataBind();
```

Comment: Nice.. Thank you!! But have to check if ExecuteReader is allowed for the solution am working on..

Comment: No problem, if you can't use ExecuteReader you are going to have to figure out a way to modify the existing data access that was created for the DLLs or use a completely different approach such as LinqToSQL or Entity Framework.  At some level all of the approaches have to execute the SQL at the base level though.